# How to calculate the accurate execution time in matlab?

Tags: matlab, time

I'm working on a stream cipher algorithm with Matlab and i want to see the difference in time with every change i made in Non-linear function. I created a Non-linear function which has some "mod" operations and "bitxor" operations, when i change some bitxor into mod operations and calculate the time using "tic toc", its shows that the new function with more "mod" operations execute with less time than the original, although the mod is slower than bitxor. What is the reason for this problem? is there an alternative way to calculate time in such case?

Comment: See https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/measure-performance-of-your-program.html

Comment: Why do you say `mod` slower than `bitxor`? Obviously it’s not, if your code speeds up replacing the one by the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use native clock, and calculate the difference. For example:

```
time1 = clock;
    [..Some heavy calculation here]
time2 = clock;
simtime = etime(time2, time1);
disp("time in seconds is:")
disp(simtime)
```

You will avoid any inaccuracy from potentially slow-downs in code execution.

Comment: I tried "clock", "cputime" and "timeit" but the problem didn't solve.

Comment: Hard to accept. It just record the time before and after process, and calculate the difference. What can goes wrong? even if `tic toc` for some reason gets lag, `clock` is independent, as it rely on system time. Without more details about your code we can't point the problem.